# Disable/Enable Buttons when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a set a grouped svg shapes, that have a class & separate ids. I have implement an onclick function on these shapes, which in turn runs another function(filter) which filters out arrays within my canvas. I also have a double click to bring back the filter arrays.

However, when I click on one of the shapes, I wish the others to be disabled until I double click on the shape that I have just clicked. I've seen many examples but appear not to work heres work I have so far:

```
function filter (d) {


  if (d.s =='triangle')  
     {d3.selectAll(".nodes").filter(function(d) {return d.categ === 'High' || d.categ === 'Low'}).transition().style("opacity", 0).style("display", "none");
        d3.selectAll("#High").on('click',function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); } ); }

else if (d.s =='cross')  
     {return d3.selectAll(".nodes").filter(function(d) {return d.categ === 'Medium' || d.categ === 'Low'}).transition().style("opacity", 0).style("display", "none");}

else {return d3.selectAll(".nodes").filter(function(d) {return d.categ === 'Medium' || d.categ === 'High'}).transition().style("opacity", 0).style("display", "none");}

   }   



function antifilter (d) {


      d3.selectAll(".nodes").transition().style("opacity", 1).style("display", "block")


 }
```

I have also attempted to use

```
     .on('click',null)
```

AND

```
      document.getElementById("High").onclick = function() { return false; }
```

But no luck. Any help would be great! So is there a way to start the mouse click again when I double click. Cant find an opposite to the stopPropagation to reset my filters.

http://jsfiddle.net/yPqqx/

Comment: not familiar with d3. Should the attribute be "enabled"?

Comment: No it seem that using stop.propagation works fine. But, is there an opposite to that so that on double click everything is back to normal?

Comment: Try setting up a demo fiddle at jsfiddle.net It can help a lot with visualizing your problem and could get you a solution faster.

Comment: Hi @jakker here's a jsfiddle to show want im trying to do. I essentially want to disable the buttons when I've click one. Then when double clicked they are all active http://jsfiddle.net/yPqqx/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a scenario about your question, have a look at

HTML

```
<span id="res">0</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="High">Link</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Enable">Enable</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Disable">Disable</a>
```

jQuery

```
function increase(){
    $("#res").text(parseInt($("#res").text()) + 1);
}
$("#High").on("click",increase);
//Enable
$(document).on("click","#Enable",function(){
    $("#High").on("click",increase);
});
//Disable
$(document).on("click","#Disable",function(){
    $("#High").off();
});
```

and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agd7H/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. This is an example of what I'm trying to do now ... http://jsfiddle.net/yPqqx/